# Не сохраняются данные в файл введенные через консоль

Tags: java

Не сохраняются данные в файл
В этом куске кода у меня создается файл и сканнер:`

```
File file = new File("xw.txt");
file.createNewFile();
FileWriter x = new FileWriter(file);
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
```

`
В этом куске кода у меня должны сохранятся данные в файле,введенные в консоль ,но почему-то не сохраняются:

```
case '1':
                    System.out.println("Enter your name:");
                    String m = scan.nextLine();
                    x.write(m);
                    System.out.println("Enter your surname:");
                    String m1 = scan.nextLine();
                    x.write(m1);
                    System.out.println("Enter your salary:");
                    String m2 = scan.nextLine();
                    x.write(m2);
                    break;
```

Я ввожу файлы через консоль,но они не сохраняются

И еще момент:у меня строка "enter your name" пропускается и сразу идет вторая.Почему?

Comment: не файлы, файл. Может в буфере данные. Закройте файл в конце -- посмотрите.

Comment: Добавьте в конце x.close();

Comment: @VincentVega забыл закрыть,пардон)А вот как вторую проблему исправить ,я не понял

Comment: Если проверять по приведенному Вами коду, то все работает нормально, за исключением того, что я уже назвал. Можете попробовать дополнить код, если тут приведен не весь. Какой средой разработки вы пользуетесь?

Comment: Также вопросы  лучше разбивать, если более 1 вопроса содержится, то лучше разбить каждый вопрос на отдельную тему. Если мой ответ решил Вашу проблему - не забудьте отметить ответ решением. И советую Вам вынести вторую проблему в отдельную тему.

Answer (score 0):

Да, правильно указано. Закройте поток
x. close();